# Button in navigation drawer menuitem not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I just try to make one Navigation Drawer Menu item to specific view. I added two textView respectively left and right side. And SwitchCompat. But SwitchCompat is not working. I just try to out one message for test.

I searched many resources but couldn't find anything like that. Is this bad practice? or not good to use?

Here my codes:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="Pay" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/paymentMethod"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:theme="@style/SelectionSwitch" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="Card" />
</LinearLayout>
```

On my Activity:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    toolbarMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).setVisible(id == R.id.nav_camera);

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        View view = item.getActionView();

      SwitchCompat payMethod = view.findViewById(R.id.paymentMethod);
            payMethod.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityHome.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

Actually after clicking more than 10 times it works but can't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

create a layout then add to menu xml :

```
<item
     android:id="@+id/nav_datasaver"
     app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_datasaver" />
```

menu_item_datasaver is the linear layout which is created in layout floder and using to menu xml

Comment: Actually this exactly what I'm doing. But doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_download"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_download"
        android:title="SAVED OFFLINE" />


        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_referral"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_refer" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contest"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_contest" />


    <!--  <item
          android:id="@+id/nav_login_button"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_download"
          android:title="LOGOUT"/>-->
</group>
```